# How to figure out, why is my shell crash?

Tags: bash, shell, crash

When I enter this command:

```
$ grep -n 'some search' $file | awk '{print 1}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -I{} vim +"{}" $file
```

It will open, but after quitting vim, the shell crash. It does not react to any input neither for Ctr-C. I have no idea why, how to find out? I suspect there is some infinite loop, because after reboot, there is a lot clearing in terminal. But really have no clue of the reason.

PS:
`alias grep`: `alias grep='grep --color=auto -P'`

`alias sed`: `alias sed='sed -E'`

No more aliases.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with an interactive command (vim)?

Comment: I just want to open `$file` at specified number `$num`, the command does that correctly for `less`, and for vim as well, but despite `less`, `vim` crash terminal after quit - which may be cause by the terminal change `vi` perform (see below in answer), I do not know how and when does `vi` changes terminal settings

Answer (score 0):

`vi` changes the terminal settings.
When you onlu want to go to the first match, you can use the linenumber with

```
vi +$(grep -n 'some search' .bashrc | cut -d: -f1 | head -1) .bashrc
```

This is still to complicated, you can jump to the match with

```
vi '/+some search/' "$file"
```

When you want to go to the second match, just use `n`.

Comment: Ok, I know there are alternative to achieve that, but can you please elaborate how the `vi` changes terminal settings, and how to customize how vi make these changes?

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/410/terminal-borked-after-invoking-vim-with-xargs or https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why